# Initialize a STL vector with object of type CPerson (class) in C++?

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I have a class `CPerson` and I want to initialize a vector of type `CPerson` with object variables. However the compiler says that `type name is not allowed`. I would like to ask why is that?

```
class CPerson {
protected:
    string m_strName; 
    Sex m_Sex; 
    Titles m_Title; 
public:
    CPerson() {
        m_strName = "Peter Petrov";
        m_Sex = male;
        m_Title = bachelor;
    }
    //добавяме параметричен к-р
    CPerson(string n,Sex s,Titles t) {
        m_strName = n;
        m_Sex = s;
        m_Title = t;
    }
    ~CPerson() {}
    void SetName(string strName) {
        m_strName = strName;
    }
    void SetSex(Sex sex) {
        m_Sex = sex;
    }
    void SetTitle(Titles title) {
        m_Title = title;
    }
    string GetName() const {
        return m_strName;
    }
};

int main(){
vector <CPerson> perr = { CPerson p1,
    CPerson p2("I.Ivanov", male, professor),
    CPerson p3("A.Stoyanova", female, assistant),
    CPerson  p4("A.Dimitrova", female, assistant)}
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of problems in your code. Here is a version of the code that compiles successfully:

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

enum class Sex {
    male, female
};

enum class Titles {
    bachelor,
    assistant,
    professor
};

class CPerson {
protected:
    std::string m_strName; 
    Sex m_Sex; 
    Titles m_Title; 
public:
    CPerson() {
        m_strName = "Peter Petrov";
        m_Sex = Sex::male;
        m_Title = Titles::bachelor;
    }
    //добавяме параметричен к-р
    CPerson(std::string n,Sex s,Titles t) {
        m_strName = n;
        m_Sex = s;
        m_Title = t;
    }

    void SetName(std::string strName) {
        m_strName = strName;
    }
    void SetSex(Sex sex) {
        m_Sex = sex;
    }
    void SetTitle(Titles title) {
        m_Title = title;
    }
    std::string GetName() const {
        return m_strName;
    }
};

int main(){
    std::vector <CPerson> perr({ 
        CPerson(),
        CPerson("I.Ivanov", Sex::male, Titles::professor),
        CPerson("A.Stoyanova", Sex::female, Titles::assistant),
        CPerson("A.Dimitrova", Sex::female, Titles::assistant)
    });
    return 0;
}
```

Besides the missing types for Sex and Titles, the main problem was in the syntax of your vector initializer. I assume that you were trying to use an initializer list, but your syntax was all wrong. It looks like you were just copying variable declaration / initialization statements into it, but you need to create new instances of your `CPerson` class. These instances will then be copied into the vector.

```
CPerson p2("I.Ivanov", male, professor)
```

Declares and initializes a variable named `p2` of class `CPerson` on the stack, but this syntax is not valid inside an initializer list, since you're not permitted to declare variables there. Instead use

```
CPerson("I.Ivanov", Sex::male, Titles::professor)
```

This creates an instance of `CPerson`, and this instance is then copied into the vector.